# Grails 4 : Database Migration plugin issue

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase, grails-4

Since upgrading to Grails 4, the migration scripts do not appear to be getting loaded from where they are configured. This results in the following error;

> liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Script text to compile cannot be
>   null!

Up to now, I had only specified the location on gradle config;

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'grails-app/migrations'
        }
    }
}
```

I have since added the additional config provided by the plugin but to no avail;

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.changelogLocation = 'grails-app/migrations'
```

Through debugging, I can see that the `grails-app/migrations` path does not appear to be added to the list of locations but also discovered that `grails-app/conf` is, so I temporarily dropped them all in there and voilà... the application fired up.

Anyone know if this is a know issue with the plugin or some missing config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated in [the github issue comment here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/issues/154#issuecomment-495351331), the `sourceSets` declaration in the gradle config file must be above the `dependencies` declaration.

Comment: :-) Forgot about this question. I actually opened that particular issue and so I'm aware of the fix, thanks though.

Comment: OK, that will be for the next ones to stumble on it as I did

Comment: There's some rep for your efforts. :-)

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. Have been facing this issue migrating from Grails 3 where it had been working fine.